# How to cut a .obj file in half?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I might seem stupid and my request may seem obvious (that's what I hope) :

I found a .obj file of a wolf head i like a lot. The thing is, for what I'm trying to do, I would only need half its head. See the wolf there :

[image: the said beast]

I tried following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3J-oYFdyqQ ; but didn't get the results I hoped : on one side, only the silhouette was kept, no more details (vertices?); and on the other that's all that was left. See there :

[image: the said failure]

If you're still with me now you probably guessed : I never used Blender before. Now as a perfect newbie I'm hoping there is a way to just cut trough that wolf like it's a cake. Is it the case ? Or am I gonna have to "try hard"? (How?)

Wishing anyone who read me all the best !

Stay safe.

Kendrick

EDIT : I managed to cut my wolf following Jachym's advices. So i do now have half my wolf :

[image: Half a wolf]

My problem is now that when i export it, i lose every detail ! I only get the shape :

[image: :(]

Are there any export settings i should consider ?

Comment: Can you share your .blend file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Bisect Tool* for that.
It's pretty simple.

1. In *Edit Mode*, select the whole mesh through *Select > All*
2. Use the *Bisect Tool* and adjust the parameters to your needs
3. Enable X-Ray Mode and select the parts you want to delete

Note: If you don't need a sharp cut, step 3. should be enough :)

---

*Use the Bisect Tool to cut the object in half*

[image]

*Then enable X-Ray mode and select the parts you want to delete*

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your awnser ! i managed to cut my wolf as i wanted, following your steps. the thing is, when i export it, i lose every detail on my wolf. i'm left with a full-white half wolf shape. are there any export settings i should consider ?

Comment: Hello :). I'd reccomend posting this as a new question. Meanwhile you can mark this answer as accepted **✓**.